# Resource Dictionary for DLL in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, resourcedictionary

Is there a way to load a resource dictionary once for a DLL and use it in all controls? I tried creating an application in the DLL that contains only the resource dictionary. This, unsurprisingly, does not work.

After fixing an issue with Build Action, this throws an exception on creating multiple applications.

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HelperWPF;component/Display/DefaultDictionary.xaml"/>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the same instance of a resource dictionary by making the following static class:

```
internal static class LoadResourceDictionary
{
    static LoadResourceDictionary()
    {
        resourceDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/DllName;component/Shared/ReusedDictionary.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
    }

    public static ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary;
}
```

Then referencing it in the class

```
public SingleAlarm_UC()
{
    this.Resources = LoadResourceDictionary.resourceDictionary;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the MergedDictionaries tag even if it is only a single ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/App.Resources;component/Styles/Brushes.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/App.Resources;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also something I have found is it does not work if you use a merged dictionary in the Resources assembly.  You need to reference each individually

Comment: When using a resource dictionary in a UserControl, the MergedDictionary is not needed. Is this something special for Application? I have only added my ResourceDictionary to UserControl.Resources before.

I am creating 50+ copies of a UserControl. I don't want to have to reload the resource dictionary for each copy. If there is a way to reference the same resource dictionary, but not to set a default dictionary that would solve my problem. 

'You need to reference each individually' -> How?

Comment: In my projects I reference the single resource dll in the main application and only need to add the resources to the App.xaml.  What I have found, though, is I cannot create a single merged dictionary in my Resources.dll and only reference that merged dictionary in App.xaml.  Should it work. Yes I do believe I should be able to reference a single merged dictionary from my Resource.dll in App.Xaml.  I could only load when I listed each individual resource file in App.xaml.  I am not saying that every single control needs to have the styles included.